# Processing high volume of records with Cassandra getting BusyPoolException

Tags: cassandra

I need to process millions of records.

what is the most efficient way to do it using phantom ?

This is how my table looks like :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
key text,

timestamp bigint,

value double,

PRIMARY KEY (key, timestamp) )
```

I am executing this query per unique key (which can reach millions)

```
select * from my_table where key = 'xyz' and timestamp >= 1504660890 and timestamp < 1504670890;
```

However at some point I am getting `BusyPoolException`

Comment: Need to make sure there is a sufficient number of node, that there is no excessive network latency, that read operations are done according the partitionning (using partition key without filtering), and that partitions are not too big (~ 100k cells / 100M). No magic solution ...

Comment: @cchantep as you can see the query is done by the partition key without filtering. not sure that I got you regarding the partition size can you elaborate regarding the calc ? I got the exception on a table with 100k records as described

Comment: check `nodetool tablehistograms`

Comment: `BusyPoolException` occurs under heavy load - no available connection and the queue has reached its max size. `PoolingOptions.setMaxRequestsPerConnection(HostDistance, int): maximum number of requests per connection;
PoolingOptions.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance, int): maximum number of connections in the pool;
PoolingOptions.setMaxQueueSize(int): maximum number of enqueued requests before this exception is thrown.`

Comment: The defaults are pretty sensible.  Even with a single node cluster and 1 pooled connection it would take 1000 simultaneous in flight requests, is it possible you are submitting all of your requests at once without any kind of limitation on your concurrency?

Comment: just out of curiosity, can't you paginate the results? Instead of reading the entire 1M

Comment: @dilsingi I not reading a lot of data . I am running a lot of queries but the result set is not large

Comment: @AndyTolbert yes you are correct I do not set a limit but the full message is `Pool is busy (no available connection and the queue has reached its max size 256)` why the size is default to 256 ?